# How to search with empty _id with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

My structure

```
struct task {
  Id *bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
  Text string `json:"text" bson:"text,omitempty"`
  // other params
}
```

Get data from form

```
var task Task{}
task.Text = FORM.Text
```

and my function to find tasks

```
func FindOne(task Task) (Task, error) {
    err := db.Session.DB("tasks").C(CollectionTask).Find(&task).One(&task)
    if err != nil {
        return task, err
    }

    return task, nil
}
```

From the search form I only get a line `text`, without a field`id`, in this case, _id -> nil and mgo (mongo) finds nothing `not found`

How do I modify the search function or structure of the data to carry out a correct search?

Comment: are you sure about the `omitempty` tag for bson _id? maybe its causing you issues

Comment: you cannot have any document in mongo without `_id`, check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#id-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working example based on your code. It first connects, then insert and finally find a specific string. As you see if you insert your documents correctly your search function works fine.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type task struct {
    ID   *bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Text string         `json:"text" bson:"text,omitempty"`
    // other params
}

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    c := session.DB("test").C("test")

    err = c.Insert(task{
        Text: "Hello",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var result task
    err = c.Find(task{
        ID:   nil,
        Text: "Hello",
    }).One(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the implementation of `insert` and found that the behavior changed, did not account for this

```
`Status string` json: "status" `
```

fixed on the `Status string 'json: "status" bson: "-"'` and everything worked properly